# CGRectContainsPoints and bounding box check is off by several pixels

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've been studying this for hours (2 days, actually) and just cannot figure out what is wrong. The touches are accepted and processing, but the `isTouchHandled` test is triggering TRUE prematurely; as if a different bounding box was touched than the one that is touched. I have several non-overlapping CCSprite buttons, with each pointed to in the `levelButtons` array. Iterate through to see which one is touched; but it's always the wrong one.

Does the `CGRectContainsPoints` method get thrown off if these sprites are in their own layer, which is then in another layer? In other words, is `CGRectContainsPoints` using raw equality of pixel locations as reported by `position`? If so, a sprite's position relative to the entire screen is different than its reported position if it is a child, which is relative to the parent. Maybe this has something to do with it? My array and the tags of its contents are correctly lining up, I've logged and checked that many times; it appears to be the bounding box check.

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CCLOG (@"levelButtons size:%i",[self.levelButtons count]);
    BOOL isTouchHandled = NO;
    for (int i=0;i<25;i++){

        CCSprite*temp=(CCSprite*)[self.levelButtons objectAtIndex:i];

        CCLOG(@"iteration temp.tag: %i for object: %i",temp.tag,i);

            isTouchHandled= CGRectContainsPoint([temp boundingBox], [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView: [touch view]]]);

        if (isTouchHandled) {

            CCLOG(@"level touched: %i",temp.tag);

            break;
        }

    }


    return isTouchHandled;
}
```

UPDATE: Incidentally, I also just subclassed CCSprite and add the touche methods to the individual sprites in this fashion ,taking my array of sprites out of the picture. The results were the same, so I suspect the CGRectContainsPoints is not properly working when your `rect` is a child of other children, the coordinates are not being reported correctly, I suspect.

Comment: using the info here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9636 I can confirm that the bounding box is indeed drawing correctly on my sprites

Comment: using logs of additional loggin of bounding box positions, i've confirmed that a bounding box of a sprite child on a layer is not relative to the screen, thus cgrectcontainspoint doesn't realize it's getting the wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new CGRect for the `CGRectContainsPoint` test, and translating the bounding box into the actual onscreen rectangle; the bounding box test will not work on its own if it is located on a child sprite (or layer). It returns its local position only, relative to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be problem with an array that you are getting sprites. Any way , this is how i am using the code for getting the sprite tag.

```
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];


for(int i1=0;i1<=25;i1++)
{
    CCSprite *sprite1 = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i1];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite1 boundingBox], location))

    {
        //Your Code
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: i see you are not using the standard bounding box checks. i doubt my array is the issue, after all the tag is on the sprite, not stored elsewhere, so if the sprite is the touched point, it should report the tag of that touch. but maybe it is due to how bounding box works in conjunction with parent-child node relationships

Comment: Ok. i updated my code. Bounding box will return the same behavior as the CGRect does...i think it is not an issue with the bounding box.